# C# If condition with Linq returns unexpected result

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I find it really weird that this condition returns `true` as a result when there are no items in the IEnumerable collection.

```
if(Results.All(r => r.Status == ResultStatus.Upload))
```

`Results` is an IEnumerable of objects and I'm basically checking if all its items' statuses are `Upload`. My workaround was first checking if the collection has items then check if all items have that status which works fine.

```
if(Results.Any() && Results.All(r => r.Status == ResultStatus.Upload))
```

Why does it not validate to `false` when there are zero items in the collection?

Comment: this is by design. It returns true if every element of the source sequence passes the test in the specified predicate, or if the sequence is empty; otherwise, false. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: "Why does it not validate to false when there are zero items in the collection?" Because all the items in the collection *do* meet the specified criteria. It's working as documented: "Returns: true if every element of the source sequence passes the test in the specified predicate, or if the sequence is empty; otherwise, false."

Comment: Thank you, makes perfect sense now

Comment: It returns `true` because no element does not pass the test.

Comment: `All` assumes true before testing collection, `Any` assumes false. so if collection is empty Any returns false.